# How to display the content for given page ID withot the <p></p> wrapper?

Tags: theme-development

How to display the content for given page ID withot the `<p></p>` wrapper?

The method I'm currently using is:

```
<?php 
$id=21; 
$post = get_page($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```

For example `page ID = 21` has the following content: `Some content`

What the wordpress echo is `<p>Some content</p>`

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this in your functions.php file for instance,

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```

Which will remove the paragraph formatting from `the_content` template tag in all cases.

Should you have a need for it in the future, you can write;

`<?php wpautop(the_content());?`> in your template to add formatting without having to add the filter back.

Using `echo get_the_content();` will by pass the WordPress `wpautop` filter too.

Here's a little function I wrote for you that you can use in your template files (paste the snippet into functions.php and see usage instructions below).

```
function custom_content($args = '', $allow = ''){

if ($args == 'alltags') {

    $type = the_content();

} elseif ($args == 'notags') {

    $type = strip_tags(wpautop(get_the_content()), $allow);

} else {

    $type = get_the_content();

    }

echo $type;

}
```

Usage:

```
<?php custom_content();?> // no <p> tags, but <a>, <strong>, etc are preserved.
<?php custom_content('notags');?> // strips all tags from content
<?php custom_content('notags', '<a>');?> // strips all tags except <a> 
<?php custom_content('notags', '<a><p><etc..>');?> // strips all tags except <a> & <p> 
<?php custom_content('alltags');?> // all tags uses the_content();
```

Now some of this might be redundant but it illustrates how you can create a multipurpose function for use within your templates that can give you some, all or no formatting based upon your situation.

Note: In case anyone is wondering why `wpautop` is wrapped around `get_the_content` above, is due to `get_the_content` not being passed through the `wpautop` filter, therefore if you want to use `<p>` tags in a specified list of allowed tags whilst using the custom `notags` argument you need to add `<p>` formatting back with `wpautop`.

Alternative for getting the content of a page based on ID and without `<p>` tags;

```
function get_content($id) {

    $post = get_page($id);
    $content = apply_filters('get_the_content', $post->post_content);
    echo $content;

}
```

Usage:

```
<?php get_content(21); ?>
```

Comment: Hmm.. This does not seams to work. Does it make any difference that I'm running this on WAMP?

Comment: Have you tried using `get_the_content` instead, this strips `P`

Comment: how do I use `get_the_content` and show page by ID at the same time, any code example please?

Comment: @NewUser See above for an update, additional snippet, that can be placed in your functions.php file and used in your template files.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `wpautop` filter ex:

```
<?php 
$id=21; 
$post = get_page($id); 
//remove auto p filter
remove_filter ('the_content','wpautop');
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
//return the filter for other posts/pages down the road
add_filter ('the_content','wpautop');
echo $content;  
?>
```

Comment: Please see here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17683975/stackoverlow/WordPress-Without-P.png  // Does not seems to work. Does it matter that I'm runnning this on WAMP?